# PHP - Best way to keep track of IPs that voted

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am making a small side project on which guests can vote on some sort of posts with either agree or disagree, then I want to save the IP that voted in the database. I was thinking of saving an array of IP's that voted in the 'posts' table, however that might be insufficient I guess. Would a separate table like the following be recommended?;
post_votes:
post_id, IP
Doesn't matter if the user voted agree or not, as long as the vote is counted they won't be able to vote again. What's the best approach for this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, I'd use a separate table for this. Storing it in an array in the `posts` table sounds horrible, and the more votes you got the slower it'd be to check for an IP. You should also store *what* their vote was (agree/disagree) alongside the vote in `post_votes`.

Comment: Separate table so you can `SELECT 1 FROM post_votes WHERE post_id = <post_id> AND IP = <ip>;` to get a quick yes or no for an IP. Otherwise you have to pull the whole damned array down and query the array in php. Indexing on post_id, mysql will query that table faster than php will query the array, and you aren't having to pull the whole array across the wire (from DB Server to Web Server).

Comment: The general rule here is to not store more than one value in a field. The only exceptions are the few times where the multiple values being stored will always be pulled together and never really change (think like.. available colors for a product). Here though you are going to constantly be pushing and popping an array on a post record, which means you have to pull the thing every time you grab the post, and that's very cumbersome. Your database will do a better job for this task.

Comment: IP != user. this wont stop me voting a million times if i wanted to

Comment: Logging in users will help.. that way you won't have to rely on IP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the best way is to use a seperate table with identifiers (e.g. post_id) to identify the posts.
Never save more than one information per field - saving the information in an array in the same table is cruel.

However, do **NOT** store the IP address 'as is' in the database as this is illegal in many countries and can cause a lot of trouble!
Instead use a hashing function like `hash_hmac` (http://php.net/manual/de/function.hash-hmac.php), hash the IP address and save the hash instead..
Because hashes are one-way functions, this will ensure anonymity for the user but still give you the opportunity to prevent users from voting several times.

Comment: "However, do NOT store the IP address 'as is' in the database as this is illegal in many countries and can cause a lot of trouble!" This would make Apache's access logs illegal. There are a few jurisdictions where you might have to be a bit careful - Germany has particularly strict privacy laws - but for the vast majority of jurisdictions IP is fine, especially if other data about the user isn't being stored associated with it.

Comment: (The hash approach is also likely to cause the same legal issues in Germany, as computing a rainbow table for all available IPs would be entirely trivial.)

Comment: Actually, not only Germany but many European countries have strict privacy laws. Depending on the definition of personal data this can indeed be a problem as courts in several countries have stated that data that can be referenced to a person already is personal data. That's why many websites declare a log of IP addresses by Apache in their privacy policy. Btw, this should've been a note to prevent trouble. Of course, using salts on the hashes is mandatory and will still not provide real security but at least prevent someone from just reading IP addresses off the table in plain text.